# Tem como saber quais tabelas tem campo Tipo Bytea numa base PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma base com 500MB eu considero pequena, mas esta lenta pra abrir algumas tabelas, verificando são tabelas que possuem campo Bytea, o outro programador guardou imagens no banco, mas está inviável trabalhar, deixou a aplicação lenta, pois as vezes as imagens não são tratadas e ficam enormes, em fim, é uma situação que posso colocar as imagens num diretório, são umas 270 tabela na base.

Tem como dar um select para que o PostgreSQL me mostre quais tem campo tipo Bytea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça a seguinte consulta:

```
select table_schema, table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns where data_type like 'bytea'
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentre as tabelas de catálogo do postgres existe a `pg_attribute` que contém as informações das colunas de todas as tabelas do database. Nessa tabela existe a coluna `atttypid` que armazena o id do tipo de dados, sendo assim, seria necessário filtrar os registros correspondentes ao tipo `bytea` conforme seu oid na tabela `pg_type`.

```
select 
    relname as tabela,
    relnamespace::regnamespace as schema,
    attname as coluna
from pg_attribute a
    inner join pg_class c
        on (a.attrelid=c.oid)
    inner join pg_type t
        on (a.atttypid=t.oid)
where typname='bytea'
    and relnamespace not in (
        'pg_catalog'::regnamespace,
        'pg_toast'::regnamespace    
    );
```

Abaixo os links com informações das tabelas de catálogo utilizadas na consulta, caso precise extrair mais informações:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalog-pg-class.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalog-pg-type.html